# Proper way to convert GeoJSON to GPX

Tags: gdal, gpx

I tried many ways to convert GIS file into GPX format but not getting proper file. I tried gpx-converter, gdal.vectorTranslate etc. Is there any other way to convert file into gpx?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: `ogr2ogr` is usually the answer for vector transforms. If that's what you've tried please add details of why it doesn't work

Comment: GPX is special format developed for waypoints, tracks, and routes. Some GIS data can be mapped into GPX elements, some other not. The core GPX also supports also just a small and fixed set of attributes, although it is possible to use extensions for non-standard attributes. Could you provide some sample data and tell what you want to do, like "I would like to convert this GeoJSON with points into GPX waypoints". It seems also that you have had some success, but what was the problem when "not getting proper file"?

Comment: Maybe try GPS Babel?  https://www.gpsbabel.org